# Symfony: how to create service from inside a bundle

Tags: symfony, service

I've created a new bundle and now I'd like to make it able to load some services.
How can I do this?

I cannot find helpful information in the documentation...

Thank you...

Comment: Why don't create ``services.yml`` inside ``Resources/config`` of particular bundle?

Comment: Creating the file as you suggested seems not working: I receive the message "You have requested a non-existent service "service.name"."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`src\MyApp\Bundle\AcmeBundle\DependencyInjection\MyAppAcmeExtension.php`

```
<?php

namespace MyApp\Bundle\AcmeBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\XmlFileLoader;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\Extension;
use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;

class MyAppAcmeExtension extends Extension
{
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $loader = new XmlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
        $loader->load('services.xml');
    }
}
```

---

`src/MyApp/Bundle/AcmeBundle/Resources/config/services.xml`

```
<container xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services
                               http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd">

    <services>
        <service id="forum.post.voter" class="MyApp\Bundle\AcmeBundle\Service\ServiceClass">
            <argument type="service" id="security.context"/>
            <argument type="service" id="forum.repository.post_like"/>
        </service>
    </services>
</container>
```

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you be more explicit ?

In which case did you need to call some services ?

If yours services are declared in services.yml you can access them in all your bundles. The only requirement is that a service name need to be unique.

Comment: this is not an answer, this is a comment